# Convert table css to gridview?

Tags: asp.net, html

I have a gridview that is bound to a database table, but the css I have to use was designed for html:table. I was wondering if there was an easy way to convert the gridview into a html table so that I can display it with the stylesheet I was given.

thanks

here's a sample of the html table my partner wrote for a mockup. I'd like to emulate how the style is applied.

```
<div class="content1">


 <table class="yep">
<thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Case #</th>
      <th>Unit #</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Type of Call</th>
      <th>Gender</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>View PCR</th>
      <th><button class="btn">Create Incident</button></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>123456788</td>
      <td>102935734</td>
      <td>07/28</td>
      <td>Critical Care</td>
      <td>Male</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td><a class="btn em" href="table_view.html">View PCR</a></td>
      <td class="check"><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
```

here's my gridview:

```
       <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="yep" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Case #" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Case #" HeaderText="Case #" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Case #" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Unit #" HeaderText="Unit #" SortExpression="Unit #" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Date" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Type of Call" HeaderText="Type of Call" SortExpression="Type of Call" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Gender" HeaderText="Gender" SortExpression="Gender" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Age" HeaderText="Age" SortExpression="Age" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="View PCR" HeaderText="View PCR" SortExpression="View PCR" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Selection">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="Selections" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Um, the grid view is rendered as table by default. Are you asking how to make it have `<thead>` and `<tbody>` tags?

Comment: Oh, I figured out how to add the head tag using gv.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader; But If you noticed the last item in the row is a button. Right now the column just has an nvarchar type. How could I convert/add the buttons to the cells in that column?

Comment: Post your `GridView` markup.

Comment: I posted my gridview code. I'd like the cells in the column "View PCR" to be buttons

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Selection">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="Selections" runat="server" OnClick="Selections_Click" CssClass="btn" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Note: The `CssClass` attribute will assign the `btn` class to the rendered output.